# How get the traceparent in OpenTelemetry?

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-platform, open-telemetry, google-cloud-trace

This is the abstraction that I've written:

```
import { context, defaultTextMapSetter } from '@opentelemetry/api';
import { W3CTraceContextPropagator } from '@opentelemetry/core';

type SqlCommentComponents = {
  traceparent?: string;
};

const renderSqlCommentComponent = (comments: SqlCommentComponents) => {
  return (
    '/*' +
    Object.entries(comments)
      .filter(([, value]) => {
        return value !== undefined;
      })
      .map(([key, value]) => {
        return `${encodeURIComponent(key)}='${encodeURIComponent(value)}'`;
      })
      .join(',') +
    '*/'
  );
};

export const getSqlcommenterComment = (): string | null => {
  const propagator = new W3CTraceContextPropagator();

  const activeContext = {};
  const sqlCommentComponents: SqlCommentComponents = {};

  propagator.inject(context.active(), activeContext, defaultTextMapSetter);

  if (
    'traceparent' in activeContext &&
    typeof activeContext.traceparent === 'string'
  ) {
    sqlCommentComponents.traceparent = activeContext.traceparent;
  }

  return Object.entries(sqlCommentComponents).length === 0
    ? null
    : renderSqlCommentComponent(sqlCommentComponents);
};
```

I then use Slonik interceptor to append the Sqlcommenter comment to the end of the SQL:

```
interceptors.push({
  transformQuery: (queryContext, query) => {
    return {
      ...query,
      sql: `${query.sql}\n${getSqlcommenterComment() ?? ''}`,
    };

    return query;
  },
});
```

The output that it produces appears to be correct:

```sql
SELECT id
FROM ip_address
WHERE
  ip_address = $1 AND
  updated_at > now() - interval '7 day'

/*traceparent='00-b1fb1430bc3932f7ad4193417161a8c0-876e8f488bbd46d2-01'*/
```

However, when viewing traces in the Cloud Trace, I don't see the associated traces, which makes me suspect that I am not generating the `traceparent` value correctly.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Your application relies on the client library to capture traces, and after updating your application to use OpenTelemetry, you don't see Cloud Trace data.

Because some Google client libraries for Go are integrated with OpenCensus, you must use an OpenCensus Bridge. You can check this [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/trace/docs/troubleshooting) as reference.